# Highcharts not loading on PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, highcharts

I am trying to implement Highcharts to display data on my web application. At the moment, I just want to see how Highchart works on my website so I have simply copied code from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/) and implemented it on my site. But for some reason, the chart does not display.

It may just be my inexperience (or quite frankly, my stupidity) but I don't know why the fiddle isn't loading. Have I missed anything?

**Here is what I have done**:

I have added the following to the `head` of the page:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/chart.js"></script>
```

`chart.js` is a seperate file, which consists of all the JavaScript from the fiddle.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: @FastSnail - I have an `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` on `chart.js:1`?

Comment: @Freddy: it seems like jQuery is not defined, try adding that to the dependencies

Comment: @Freddy yes add jquary first .in above example fiddle it has jQuery loaded .if you click javascrippt icon , under Frameworks & Extensions you can see `jQuery1.9.1`

Comment: @JonathanM.Hethey - You're right, guess it was my stupidity which was causing the graph not to load aha. Thanks!

Comment: @FastSnail - Yes it was the missing jQuery! Got it working now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you observe a problem, the first thing you need to check is whether there are any errors. When it comes to Javascript, you need to check the browser console. In this case, the `$` in the error message is a strong hint that you forgot to include a `script` tag before the other `script` tags having its `src` attribute pointing to the location of jquery.